# IOTA Hub Uncontrollable Rollbacks

Tags: hub

When I am running iota, connecting to public node, I am constantly recieving this error:

```
Aug 26 00:39:48 marx hub[31418]: E0826 00:39:48.114866 31429 user_address_monitor.cc:122] On-Tangle sum for address: O9TGBUQLTACYETFRDTRERWZT9SPCVRPZGGGMNGSZVBDYWI9UPLBFNXAFBYKRNBLZIBVREV9ZUFMRTHQHX did not match expected. Expected (getBalances): 150 observed: 0
Aug 26 00:39:48 marx hub[31418]: E0826 00:39:48.115031 31429 user_address_monitor.cc:136] Controlled rollback.
Aug 26 00:39:48 marx hub[31418]: MySQL debug: Executing: 'ROLLBACK'
```

It keeps saying ROLLBACK, and it knows that the value on the ledger is 150 `Expected (getBalances): 150` but for some reasion it is not showing up in the account...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

If anyone comes here with the issue I have a vague solution. The first issue is the IOTA node you are connected to. The IOTA Hub should be running on a powerful computer, not a pi. Secondly, the IOTA node should not be public, have a strong computer that is isolated to just IOTA hornet node, ideally on the same computer as your IOTA HUB. This will most likely solve your issue. Other wise you need to do make sure your nodes are powerful, then backup the mysql database (for the seeds if there is money in it), then clean the mysql database and restart the hub.

**In Summary**

To not have any issues with IOTA Hub:

1. Run Hornet and IOTA Hub on the same server
2. Have the resources of 4 cores and 8gb of ram and 50 GB disk space (reccomended). Minimum of 2 cores and 4gb of ram.